# Gradle mixing build flavours

Tags: android, gradle

Is there a way of "mixing" multiple flavours in gradle?

For example, let's say I have two flavours: `Red` and `Blue`. Now let's say I have two flavours that I want these to have (sub-flavours, if you like): `Complex` and `Simple`.

What I know so far is that this would require me to create four flavours: `Red-Complex`, `Red-Simple`, `Blue-Complex`, `Blue-Simple`.

I'm unclear on how this should be structured within the project. How do I define `Red` code that is shared between the `Red-Complex` and `Red-Simple` flavours, but also have the `Complex` code that is shared between `Red-Complex` and `Blue-Complex`? I don't want to have to copy/paste code between the flavours.

What's the best way to achieve this in gradle?

Comment: I am having similar issues, except mine is `Branding1-Code1`, `Branding1-Code2`, `Branding2-Code1`, `Branding2-Code2`. The structure i have is`main` , `Branding2`. But now I need to swap code for an Activity

Answer (score 0):

Here is how flavor works: https://proandroiddev.com/advanced-android-flavors-part-1-building-white-label-apps-on-android-ade16af23bcf

-> In Your src folder you want to create 2 flavors called "red", "blue".

-> Create 2 folder named "red", "blue" in src (same level as main).

-> folder hasesame structure as main.

-> Here you have the option to override any XML/resources/java files/values etc.

-> (resources having the same name as main will override when you build a Flavour).

-> Use sample code in build.gradle  to add flavor in the project.

```
productFlavors {
      blue{
          minSdkVersion 21
          applicationId 'something'
          targetSdkVersion 28
          versionCode 1
          versionName "1.0.0"
      }
      red
      {
          minSdkVersion 21
          applicationId 'something'
          targetSdkVersion 28
          versionCode 1
          versionName '1.0.0'
      }
  }

  buildTypes {
      Debug {   }
      Release { }
  }
```

Will give the build variants :

```
blueDebug
blueRelease
redDebug
redRelease
```

//================ Add sub flavors to it ================

Here: https://proandroiddev.com/advanced-android-flavors-part-2-enter-flavor-dimensions-4ad7f486f6

->  To have Sub-flavors like Simple, Complex ( In other words "buildTypes").

->  For Sub-Flavours or say buildTypes we use dimensions.

-> flavorDimensions "Flavour", "SubFlavour"  (in your build.gradle)
// Can be any keyword, use internally 
// think of this keyword as group id who define a collection of flavors as a group.

-> Use this in your flavors
 -> We can think Key word "dimension" is more of like defining a set of flavor and sub-flavor

```
flavorDimensions "Flavour", "SubFlavour" 
  productFlavors
  { 
      // group one
      Simple {
          dimension "SubFlavour"
      }
      Complex {
          dimension "SubFlavour"
      }

      //group two
      // Take a note: do not use upper case in your flavours (one which match the folder names in src)
      // Sub-Flavours can have Upper case
      blue
      {
          dimension "Flavour"
          minSdkVersion 21
          applicationId 'something'
          targetSdkVersion 28
          versionCode 1
          versionName "1.0.0"
      }
      red
      {
          dimension "Flavour"
          minSdkVersion 21
          applicationId 'something'
          targetSdkVersion 28
          versionCode 1
          versionName '1.0.0'
      }
  }
```

--> By configure this correctly you will see below buildVariants.

```
 blueSimpleDebug
  blueSimpleRelease
  blueComplexDebug
  blueComplexRelease

  redSimpleDebug
  redSimpleRelease
  redComplexDebug
  redComplexRelease
```

//================= build.gradle ================
// Here your build.gradle might look like.

```
android {

    buildTypes {
        debug {   }
        release { }
        // Any other you want to add here
        // Ex, development {}
    }


    flavorDimensions "Flavour", "SubFlavour"
    productFlavors {
        Simple {
            dimension "SubFlavour"
        }
        Complex {
            dimension "SubFlavour"
        }

        Blue
        {
            dimension "Flavour"
            minSdkVersion 21
            applicationId 'something'
            targetSdkVersion 28
            versionCode 1
            versionName "1.0.0"
        }
        Red
        {
            dimension "Flavour"
            minSdkVersion 21
            applicationId 'something'
            targetSdkVersion 28
            versionCode 1
            versionName '1.0.0'
        }

    }
    sourceSets {
        main {
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src/main/aidl', 'src/main/res/animation', 'src/main/res/animations']
            res.srcDirs = [

                    'src/main/res/anim',
                    'src/main/res/layouts/xyz',
                    'src/main/res/layouts/abc',
                    'src/main/res/layouts',
                    'src/main/res/layout',
                    'src/main/res'
            ]
            resources.srcDirs = ['src/main/resources', 'src/main/resources/xml']
            manifest.srcFile 'src/main/AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src/main/java']
        }
        red {
            java.srcDirs = ['src/red/java']
            res.srcDirs = [
                    'src/red/res/layouts/xyz',
                    'src/red/res/layouts/abc',
                    'src/red/res/layouts',
                    'src/red/res'
            ]
            assets.srcDirs = ['src/red/assets']
            manifest.srcFile 'src/red/AndroidManifest.xml'
        }
        blue {
            java.srcDirs = ['src/blue/java']
            res.srcDirs = [
                    'src/blue/res/layouts/xyz',
                    'src/blue/res/layouts/abc',
                    'src/blue/res/layouts',
                    'src/blue/res'
            ]
            assets.srcDirs = ['src/blue/assets']
            manifest.srcFile 'src/blue/AndroidManifest.xml'
        }

    }

} //andorid

dependencies {
// yout dependencies
}
```