# Android gradle two different launcher activities for two different product flavors

Tags: android, gradle, build.gradle

This is my case

```
productFlavors {
    paid {
        applicationId "com.paid.app"
    }
    free {
        applicationId "com.free.app"
    }
}
```

and in `paid` flavor I need a different launcher activity in comparison to `main` or `free` as done below

```
main/AndroidManifest.xml

  <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

paid/AndroidManifest.xml

  <activity
        android:name=".SecondMainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

And when I begin to install app in `paid` build variants, it always install two apps i.e. free and paid but with same app name. And when I uninstall any one , both the app gets uninstalled. Shouldn't only `paid` variant build a paid app and `free` variant build a free app? Following is my working environment

```
  dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.0'
   }
  Android Studio 1.4 beta 2
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are not installing 2 apps.

Using the paid flavor in your Manifest you will merge 2 Activities with the LAUNCHER category.

```
 <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />    
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
 </intent-filter>
```

In this way you will have 2 icons to launch your app. One for the `MainActivity`,one for the `SecondActivity`.

If you want a different Activity for each flavor,you have to use the same Activity in each flavor.

```
app/src/free/java/..../MainActivity
app/src/paid/java/..../MainActivity
```

Comment: Thanks for the info. I know on making same `Activity` on different flavors to make two different apps. I was curious whether same can be done with two different default or launcher activity.

Comment: @laaptu if you would like different default or launcher activity, the way is the same. Define the same class in the flavor folder (not in main)

Comment: Thanks for the info. So there seems no workaround with different Activity. Only option is defining the same Activity in product flavor folder and modifying as per necessity.

Comment: I had done the second method, but get "duplicate class found" error. So unsure how it is supposed to work.

Comment: @Doomsknight may be you are getting "duplicate class" because you are using the same class in a flavor and in the main folder. You can't do it.

Comment: Thanks, that is the reason. Just trying to figure out how to use one class for two flavours, and another for the other 2 now. :) Without creating copies.

Comment: Does this question make sense, and do you know the solution please? [link to question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30211868/gradle-mixing-build-flavours)

Comment: correct decision is here https://stackoverflow.com/a/34183747/345810

Answer (score 30):

Actually you can do that, with having 2 manifest files and without duplicating the activity:

main/AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<activity
    android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

paid/AndroidManifest.xml:

```
 <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
     package="com.yourpackage">
         <activity
              android:name=".MainActivity"
              android:label="@string/app_name">
                  <intent-filter tools:node="remove">
                        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
                  </intent-filter>
         </activity>
         <activity
              android:name=".SecondMainActivity"
              android:label="@string/app_name">
                  <intent-filter>
                      <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                      <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                  </intent-filter>
        </activity>

</manifest>
```

meaning that at manifest merge for paid flavor you remove the intent-filter that defines the launcher activity from main and add it to SecondMainActivity.