# exclude activities from building with signed apk

Tags: android, apk

I have a program with some activities that are used in one flavor but not used in another one.
My question is how can I exclude these activities from being built in this flavor which doesn't use them?

Comment: Have you tried android:enabled="false" in the Manifest <activity> </activity>?

Comment: use build flavors https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32324213/android-gradle-two-different-launcher-activities-for-two-different-product-flavo